# Making amazon S3 bucket searchable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudsearch

I have two buckets with large quantity of pdf files. And, I wanted to make these searchable with file name and content after indexing all documents. I tried using the CloudSearch but it appeared to be useful for same data type. Please guide me how I can make documents searchable in amazon s3 bucket for a domain name or using any web browser.

Answer (score 4):

CloudSearch can index PDFs. You can submit that data from S3 buckets using the AWS CLI or the web console. This functionality is documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/uploading-data.html

If you want something automated, AWS Lambdas can monitor your buckets for changes and submit new documents for indexing.